# Python. Код в учебнике не работает: создание экземпляра класса

Tags: python, классы

survey.py

```
class AnonymousSurvey():
    """Сбор анонимных ответов на опросы"""
    def __init__(self, question):
        '''Сохраняет вопрос и готовится к сохранению ответов'''
        self.question = question
        self.responses = []

    def show_question(self):
        '''выводит вопрос'''
        print(question)

    def store_response(self, new_response):
        '''сохраняет один ответ на вопрос'''
        self.responses.append(new_response)

    def show_results(self):
        '''выводит все полученные ответы'''
        print("Survey results:")
        for response in responses:
            print("- " + response)
```

---

language_survey.py

```
from survey import AnonymousSurvey

#Определение вопроса с созданием экземпляра AnonymousSurvey
question = 'What language did you first lean to speak?'
my_survey = AnonymousSurvey(question)

# Вывод опроса и сохранение ответов
my_survey.show_question()
print("Enter 'q' at any time to quit. \n")
while True:
    response = input("language: ")
    if response == 'q':
        break
    my_survey.store_response(response)

# Вывод результатов опроса
print("\nThank you to everyone who participated in the survey!")
my_survey.show_results()
```

ошибка

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python\files\language_survey.py", line 8, in <module>
    my_survey.show_question()
  File "C:\Python\files\survey.py", line 10, in show_question
    print(question)
NameError: name 'question' is not defined
```

Этот код из книги Мэтиза, но у меня почему то не работает.

Comment: Вероятно стоит внимательнее посмотреть в книгу и перепечатать без ошибок.

Comment: `print(self.question)`

Comment: В методе `show_question` пропущено `self`. `print(self.question)`.

Answer (score 2):

Если внимательно посмотреть на параметры, передаваемые в функцию:

```
def show_question(self):
        '''выводит вопрос'''
        print(question)
```

То увидите, что передается только параметр `self`.

Отсюда должен появиться вопрос, что такое в данной функции `question`.

Как выше вам ответили, вам обращаться к `question` у `self`:

`print(self.question)`

Приучайтесь внимательнее следить за параметрами, с которыми работаете. Тем более если ошибка указывает прямиком на нужное место:)